# Adjusting the directory declared within stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis, etl

There are multiple stored procedures where a variable lets say

```
@filepath = '//c:/users/public/adp_file/processed'
```

is declared. Now I  need to  replace only specific portion of the directory path such as `c:/user/public` with `//nclas/localnca/` and get result as

```
@filepath = '//nclas/localnca/adp_file/processed'
```

for all the stored procedure within different databases.

**FYI**: there are many databases having such stored procedure where `@filepath` is declared with this `c:/user/public` portion in the directory path.

At present I am manually doing by using find and replace option for every stored procedure one by one. I was wondering is there any efficient way to get it done.

Comment: You are going to have to manually update your procedures. However I would strongly suggest you move the path to a table and update your procedures to query that table. That way the next time you need to update the path you simply change the value in your table.

Comment: You might to take a look at sql search. It is a free tool from redgate you can use to make sure you find all the places in your code you reference your path.

Answer (score 0):

You can do database by database: by scripting the stored procedures (all stored procs in the database) to files, then use Replace in files (Notepad++ or VisualStudio, and many others), and then run those files.